# Apache or WordPress plugin that redirects /?amp=1 to normal url

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect, amp-html

I am looking for a way to properly redirect **/?amp=1** urls to normal urls as I have removed amp from my website. I run apache so a .htaccess solution or a WordPress plugin that can handle /?amp=1 redirects would be welcome ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this to remove the `/?amp=1` from your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /\?amp=1
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1? [L,R]
```

Comment: This unfortunately does not work. The source: https://www.meervoormamas.nl/3-gezonde-pannenkoeken/?amp=1 redirects to https://meervoormamas.nl/lifestyle/recepten/gezonde-makkelijke-en-lekkere-pannenkoeken-recepten/?amp=1 
As seen, the /?amp=1 stays in the url

Comment: @MaltaCode This works. You just need to put this at the top of your htaccess file before other rules.

Comment: Thanks, now it does work ;-)

Comment: @MaltaCode `R` in the code above represents a temporary redirect with 302 status. You can change it to `R=301` to make the redirection permanent.